# getting this error "integer expression expected : line 10 and 23" in this bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to check a number is palindromic or not. I used a function called `pal()`. I'm getting this error that says:

```
./pal.sh: line 10: [: input: integer expression expected
./pal.sh: line 23: [: input: integer expression expected
```

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

pal()
{
  num=$1
  rnum=$num
  add=0
  k=0

  while [ $num -ne 0 ]
  do
    lev=1
    mod= $num % 10
    for((i=0;i<$k;i++))
    do
      lev=`expr $lev \* 10`
    done
    mul=`expr $mod \* $lev`
    add=`expr $add + $mul`
    num=`expr $num / 10`
    k=`expr $k + 1`
  done
  if [ $rnum -eq $add ]
  then
    echo "pallindrome"  
  else
    echo "not pallindrome"
  fi

}
echo "input number"
read input
pal input
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What value are you typing into the program?  What do you get when you run it with `bash -x yourscript`?  If the internals of the function are not displayed, add `set -x` to the start of the function to enable tracing.  This is basic shell script debugging technique; it will help you in future.

Comment: `mod= $num % 10` => `mod=$((num % 10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the value of the variable, not its name:

```
pal $input
```

Also, as [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292042/getting-this-error-integer-expression-expected-line-10-and-23-in-this-bash-s/21292151#comment32086544_21292042), you will need to fix the arithmetic in the function:

```
mod= $num % 10
```

should be:

```
mod=$(($num % 10))
```

or:

```
((mod = $num % 10))
```

You should also generally avoid using `expr` in `bash` — there are built-in facilities to handle pretty much anything `expr` can handle.

Comment: Thank you so much.It's been really helpful.Would you please suggest any good website where i can find most of the "built-in facilities?"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `rev` from "util-linux" like so,

```
#!/bin/bash
pal()
{
  input=$1
  if [ $input == $(echo $input | rev) ]; then 
    echo "pallindrome" 
  else 
    echo "not pallindrome"
  fi
}
echo "input number"
read input
pal $input
```

Output

```
$ ./pal.sh
input number
101
pallindrome
$ ./pal.sh
input number
102
not pallindrome
```

Comment: Do you really need `/dev/stdin` like that? Surely `rev` will read from standard input when no file name is given.

Comment: Thanks.I'm just started bash shell programming, so i didn't understand the "rev" which is used above.

Comment: @user3224936 It's another command (from util-linux); [here](http://ss64.com/bash/rev.html) is the man page (or use `man rev`).